# Is the $\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{span}(S))=\operatorname{span}(S)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{span}(S))=\operatorname{span}(S)$$

Does that statement hold true?  I think it does since it is just the span of the span, but how would one prove this?

Comment: It does hold true.  How you would prove it depends on what property you use as the definition of the span of a set.  One good property to know (which is occasionally used as a definition) is that a span of a set is the intersection of all (linear) subspaces containing that set.

Comment: In other words, "span" is a closure operation.

Answer (score 2):

$\operatorname{Span}(s)=V$ is a vector space, and a vector space is by definition closed under the operation of taking linear combinations of its elements. Since the span of $V$ consists of linear combinations of elements of $V$, we see that $\operatorname{Span}(\operatorname{Span}(s))=\operatorname{Span}(V) = \operatorname{Span}(s)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\span}{\operatorname{span}}$

**Hint:** consider a generating family of $\span(S)$ and write everything
explicitely.

full details:

You have that $\span (S)\subset \span(\span (S))$ immediately.

Let $\{e_i, 1\le i \le n\}$ be a generating family of $\span (S)$.

Let $k\ge 1$, $a_1,\dots, a_m\in \span (S)$ with
$$
a_l = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{lk} e_k
$$
and let $x = \sum_{l=1}^m A_l a_l\in \span(\span(S))$.

Then
$$
x = \sum_{l=1}^m A_l a_l = \sum_{l=1}^m A_l \sum_{k=1}^n a_{lk} e_k
= \sum_{k=1}^n\left[\sum_{l=1}^m A_la_{lk}\right] e_k\in \span(S).
$$

Conclusion:
$$
\span (S)\subset \span(\span (S))\\
\span(\span (S))\subset \span (S)\\
\implies \span (S)= \span(\span (S))
$$

Comment: Do you think giving a hint would be better than a full solution?

Comment: ok, I made an edit.

Comment: This answer presupposes that $S$ is contained in a finite-dimensional subspace of the original vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Let ${\bf x}$ be a vector in ${\rm span}({\rm span}(S))$.  By definition,
$${\bf x}=\lambda_1{\bf s}_1+\cdots+\lambda_n{\bf s}_n$$
for some scalars $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ and some vectors ${\bf s}_1,\ldots,{\bf s}_n$ in ${\rm span}(S)$.  But we can also, by definition of span, write
$${\bf s}_1=\mu_{1,1}{\bf s}_{1,1}+\cdots+\mu_{1,m}{\bf s}_{1,m}$$
and so on, where $\mu_{k,l}$ are scalars and ${\bf s}_{k,l}$ are vectors in $S$.  Substituting these into the previous equation shows that ${\bf x}$ is a linear combination of vector in $S$, so ${\bf x}\in{\rm span}(S)$.

Thus ${\rm span}({\rm span}(S))$ is a subset of ${\rm span}(S)$.

Conversely, if $\bf x$ is in ${\rm span}(S)$ then it is already a linear combination of vectors in ${\rm span}(S)$, and therefore is in ${\rm span}({\rm span}(S))$.