# let $S$ be a subset of a vector space $V$, are $\mathrm{span}(S)$ and $\mathrm{span(span}(S))$ the same subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I believe it is they are, but I am not one hundred percent on this one.

Comment: [Is the $\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{span}(S))=\operatorname{span}(S)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739079/is-the-operatornamespan-operatornamespans-operatornamespans) and [Prove span(span(s)) = span(s)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609801/prove-spanspans-spans)

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are.
To prove they are equal, you can prove that $\mathrm{span}(S) \subset \mathrm{span(span}(S))$, and $\mathrm{span(span}(S)) \subset \mathrm{span}(S)$.

The first direction is trivial, because $\mathrm{span(span}(S))$ contains $\mathrm{span}(S)$ by definition.

For the other direction, let $W = \mathrm{span}(S)$. Then $W$ is a vectorspace containing $\mathrm{span}(S)$. However, $\mathrm{span(span}(S))$ is the smallest vector space containing $\mathrm{span}(S)$ by definition, so $\mathrm{span(span}(S)) \subset W = \mathrm{span}(S)$.

Hence the set containment goes both ways, so $\mathrm{span}(S) = \mathrm{span(span}(S))$

Comment: That’s not the usual definition of the span of a set of vectors. The usual definition is the set of all of their linear combinations. The fact you cite is more usually presented as a theorem.

Comment: I wouldn't say that, from what I've seen it's half-and-half. The first linear algebra course I took used the definition I cited, and later showed that it's equivalent to the set of linear combinations. Personally I'd say it comes down to the book/course.